# Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint when forward engineering

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

when I try to forward engineer my new schema, I am getting this error. Anyone can offer your assistance to ?

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `SLIOP`.`schedule`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SLIOP`.`schedule` (
      `scheduleID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `lecturerID` INT NOT NULL,
      `courseID` INT NOT NULL,
      `type` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`scheduleID`),
      INDEX `fk_schedule_academic_staff1_idx` (`lecturerID` ASC),
      INDEX `fk_schedule_course1_idx` (`courseID` ASC),
      CONSTRAINT `lecturerID`
        FOREIGN KEY (`lecturerID`)
        REFERENCES `SLIOP`.`academic_staff` (`lecturerID`)
        CONSTRAINT `courseID`
        FOREIGN KEY (`courseID`)
        REFERENCES `SLIOP`.`course` (`courseID`)
        ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Parent tables

```
     -- -----------------------------------------------------
     -- Table `SLIOP`.`course`
     -- -----------------------------------------------------
     CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SLIOP`.`course` (
     `courseID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `course_code` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
     `course_name` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
     `lecturer_name` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
     `time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
     `fee` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
     `requirement` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL,
     `lecturerID` INT NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`courseID`),
     ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `SLIOP`.`academic_staff`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SLIOP`.`academic_staff` (
 `lecturerID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `first_name` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
 `last_name` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
 `profile_image` BLOB NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`lecturerID`))
 ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I have searched related posts here, but i couldn't find where is my error.

Comment: I'm surprised MySQL didn't return a syntax error; I'm surprised the statement execution got as far as it did, what with the missing comma between the constraint definitions, the missing closing paren...

Comment: I am still getting the error after coding the closing braces. Please assistance me to find the problem.

Comment: Did MySQL Workbench generate this code? I very much doubt it. There are several simple syntax errors (as indicated in the answer) which are probably caused by yourself. So, how comes?

Comment: Yes I did. But the error is still shown.

Answer (score 0):

Main issue I believe is a missing comma before `CONSTRAINT courseID`

But you missed several closing braces as well.

So here are working statements:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2bb11

```
     CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `course` (
     `courseID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `course_code` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
     `course_name` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
     `lecturer_name` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
     `time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
     `fee` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
     `requirement` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL,
     `lecturerID` INT NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`courseID`)
     )
     ENGINE = InnoDB;

 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `academic_staff` (
 `lecturerID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `first_name` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
 `last_name` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
 `profile_image` BLOB NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`lecturerID`))
 ENGINE = InnoDB;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `schedule` (
      `scheduleID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `lecturerID` INT NOT NULL,
      `courseID` INT NOT NULL,
      `type` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`scheduleID`),
      INDEX `fk_schedule_academic_staff1_idx` (`lecturerID` ASC),
      INDEX `fk_schedule_course1_idx` (`courseID` ASC),
      CONSTRAINT `lecturerID`
        FOREIGN KEY (`lecturerID`)
        REFERENCES `academic_staff` (`lecturerID`),
        CONSTRAINT `courseID`
        FOREIGN KEY (`courseID`)
        REFERENCES `course` (`courseID`))
        ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to create the tables without any issue, after correcting the syntax errors. Just make sure you are running the scripts in correct order. i.e.
Table **SLIOP.schedule** should be created last since it is referencing 
**`SLIOP`.`academic_staff`** and **`SLIOP`.`course`**